# Zoom and pinch events not fired in Desktop using javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

Im trying to create a function for app idle timeout. I registered all touch events using Gesture object. Doing these static events are fired. But zoom, pinch and cursor move are not fired. Any sussestions?

```
var count = 0;
var max = 15;
var myGesture = new MSGesture();
myGesture.target = document.body;

document.body.addEventListener("pointerdown", function (evt) {
    // adds the current mouse, pen, or touch contact for gesture recognition
    myGesture.addPointer(evt.pointerId);
});
document.body.addEventListener("MSGestureStart", eventListener, false);
document.body.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd", eventListener, false);
document.body.addEventListener("MSGestureChange", eventListener, false);
document.body.addEventListener("MSInertiaStart", eventListener, false);
document.body.addEventListener("MSGestureTap", eventListener, false);
document.body.addEventListener("MSGestureHold", eventListener, false);
setTimer();


function setTimer() {
    if (count == max)
        window.close();
    else {
        count = count + 1;
        t = setTimeout(setTimer, 1000);
    }

}


function eventListener(evt) {
    clearTimeout(t);
    count = 0;
    setTimer();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your pointerdown handler you need to add code to reflect when two (or more) fingers are down.

There you will be able to multi touch gestures like zoom or pinch

**edit:** not mine, but take a look at this code http://pastebin.com/frAqdhGj

Comment: How do you do that. Could you share a snippet please. But even swipe is not working. Only click and hold is working.

Comment: Which part of that code handles multi touch gestures..please help me out